# Working with ReactJS and HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, reactjs

I have a root component that renders `<Particle />` components and `<Particle />` component render function is:

```
render: function(){
        var data = this.props.data,
            canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
            context;

        canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
        canvas.style.top = data.y + 'px';
        canvas.style.left = data.x + 'px';
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(data.img, data.x, data.y, data.tileSize, data.tileSize, 0, 0, data.tileSize, data.tileSize);

        return canvas;
    }
```

And this returns the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Particle.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
```

I had a look at Flipboard's `react-canvas` but I couldn't find any good examples similar to my situation.

So any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just return a single canvas element with a reference to it. This element is not the same as a DOM node; React transforms it into a React Component using JSX:

```
render: function() {
    return <canvas ref="canvas" />
}
```

Then modify it inside a lifecycle method:

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function() {
    var canvas = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.canvas);
    canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
    // etc ...
}
```

You could also set some inline style attributes inside the render:

```
render: function() {
    var styles = {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: this.props.data.y,
        left: this.props.data.x
    }
    return <canvas ref="canvas" style={styles} />
}
```

...but the context/drawimage would be best to put in a lifecycle method since you need access to the dom node.